# passing url variable with my jquery script to the serverside file

Tags: php, jquery

i have a pagination script which working with jquery and php scripts, i am trying here to pass a url variable called `rev` in my url which give the pagination server side file a sql id parameter

here is my jquery code:

```
function loadData(page){
                    loading_show(); 

                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "commentPagination.php",
                        data: "page="+page,

                        success: function(msg)
                        {
```

i tried the following but it did not work

```
function loadData(page){
                    loading_show(); 

                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "commentPagination.php",
                        data: "page="+page+"&rev="+rev,

                        success: function(msg)
                        {
```

which it did not work , how can i get the variable from the URL then pass it through the jquery to my server side file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use an Object as the data attribute

```
//...
   data: {
       page: page,
       rev: rev
   },
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an object:

```
data: {page: page, rev: rev},
```

Though you might want to rename your variables so that you won't be confused.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Here is the complete code you are looking for:

```
 $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "get-cities-xml/"+area,
                            data: "eid=0",
                            dataType: "xml",
                            success: function(data) {
                                $html = "";
                                $(data).find("city-name").each(function(){
                                    $html += "<li><a class='aclick' href='getproperty/"+$(this).find("name").text()+"'>"+$(this).find("name").text()+"</a></li>";

                                });
                                $("#show-cities").html("<ul>"+$html+"</ul>");
                            },
                        error:function(xhr,err){
                          //alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
                         alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);


                        }

                        });
```

Now for your thing:

```
$.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "commentPagination.php",
                        data: "page="+page,

                        success: function(msg)
                        {
alert(msg)// that msg contains ur html response.
},
```